# Grid with five cells in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way to get 5 cell Grid per row using `sap.ui.layout.Grid`.

I am able to get 6 Cells when the `span` is 2,
4 cells when the `span` is 3 and 
3 cells when the `span` is 4.

But cannot seem to get 5 cell row using this control. thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

By default a Grid acts as a separation of the screen by 12 columns. The span indicates the size of each section you want to divide. In your example with a span of 2, the result is 6 Cells since 12/2 = 6.

Since you cannot specify a decimal size for the span, what you can do is play around with the indentation. If you choose a span of 2 like in your example but you use an indentation on the first element of 1, only 5 columns will appear since you won't have enough space for the sixth one (1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 11 -> hence no space for a +2 column). A quick example that will allow you to see this in action is as such:

```
<mvc:View
       xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
       xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
       xmlns="sap.ui.commons"
       controllerName="sap.ui.layout.sample.GridProperties.GridProperties"
       xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<l:VerticalLayout
            width="100%">
<l:Grid defaultSpan="XL2 L2 M5 S12" position="Center">
<l:content>
  <Label text="Text">
   <layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="XL2 L2" indent="XL1" />
    </layoutData>
  </Label>
    <Label text="Text">
    <layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="XL2 L2"/>
    </layoutData>
  </Label>
    <Label text="Text">
    <layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="XL2 L1" />
    </layoutData>
  </Label>
    <Label text="Text">
    <layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="XL2 L2" />
    </layoutData>
  </Label>
  <Label text="Text">
    <layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="XL2 L2" />
    </layoutData>
  </Label>
  <Label text="Text">
    <layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="XL2 L2" />
    </layoutData>
  </Label>
</l:content>
</l:Grid>
</l:VerticalLayout>
</mvc:View>
```

If you remove the indent from the first label, you'll see the 6 labels in the same row, otherwise only 5 will appear.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Definitely in the right direction, but two issues: 1. since i am using sap.m. * controls, it is not letting me add the "layoutData" to my view. 2. In the xml view my Grid content is dynamic to my model:

Comment: per documentation, the size of the screen is converted to 12 columns for the Grid. Is it possible to extend this control and change it to 15 columns?

Comment: What kind of sap.m controls are you using? Just tried with combobox and button and there was no problem with the layoutdata. As for your content being dynamic, looking at some code would probably help fix the issue but I understand what you're trying to say, you don't know beforehand how many components you will have.
I have never seen or read anything that allows us to change the number of columns for the Grid control (which does not mean it's not possible, but I highly doubt it).

Comment: Mt attempt to add layout data in the xml view failed. In the controller I was trying to add the indent for the first cell by getting the content of the Grid in the function onBeforeRendering. But my content is empty, which is is strange. I was able to to use another control's event (Combo box change) to get the Grids content and add the indent. Does it mean i cannot Access the Grid's content in the onBeforeRendering function?